# how to make bubble tip in android listView

Tags: android-listview

I want to ask that any one can tell me how to make bubble tips in android ListView like this
[image]

This tip may show the count of listItems of the next listView which appears after clicking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery mobile - data-count-theme for count bubbles - that's the only way i know.

Comment: here's a fiddle - i didn't make it but it's useful! http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/h3vuv/1/

Comment: how can we access it in native java . without JQM ?